# How to get a specific row of data for mysql with specification of company and agent

Tags: mysql

How to retrieve all the data pertaining to company name and agent from mysql? How to write the query statement?

[image]

Comment: embed the image into the question, do not link it

Comment: Did you try Select * to get row data? And also can you please clarify more? Like Table schema and what query are you executing?

Comment: they dnt allow embedding for me

Comment: I am trying to specify a query to get a specific data based on company and agent from a table for mysql. Because I am creating a website where users can only access based on their name and company so need to retrieve specifically based on company name and agent.

Comment: thank you O.Jones!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM agent_info
WHERE policyCompany = 'Avia' and policyAgent = 'Ron';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess because you didn't tell us much about your tables, but this might work.

```
SELECT policyCompany, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT policyAgent ORDER BY policyAgent) agents
FROM mytable
GROUP BY policyCompany
```

You can read about GROUP_CONCAT() [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: thank you! I will try to learn as much I can.